# Validate XML against a TLD (Tag Library Descriptors) file

Tags: xml, validation, xmlstarlet, tld, xmllint

I'm searching for a command-line program (running in Cygwin bash) which would validate XML files against a TLD description.

I've looked at `xmlstarlet` and `xmllint` but don't find any option to validate against TLD files.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The question is not about a particular file to validate, but which Tools to use. And, given I don't find information about how to validate with a TLD, my question may be somehow wrong, but I definitily don't know more about this to be able to go a step further.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are **off-topic for Stack Overflow**. Your question is better suited to [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: I think this post will help you. Really is a C code to validate an XML against a XSD file: http://knol2share.blogspot.com.es/2009/05/validate-xml-against-xsd-in-c.html . Youll need a C compiler and dependencies installed